# Response.Redirect is not passing the value to another webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, query-string

I am trying to pass a textbox value in `ClientGroupRegistration.aspx` to a label in `BorrowerRegistration.aspx`. I am using the QueryString method, however, the following code is not working for me. No value gets passed to `relationshipNameLabel.Text`.

From **ClientGroupRegistration.aspx**

```
protected void nextPageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ClientGroup client = new ClientGroup(this.addRelationshipName, this.addRelationshipComments);
    Response.Redirect("~/WebPages/BorrowerRegistration.aspx?Parameter=" + client.ClientName().ToString(), false); //ClientName() method returns a client name
}
```

To **BorrowerRegistration.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    relationshipNameLabel.Text = Request.QueryString["Parameter"];                  
}
```

Comment: Please load the first page in Chrome. Load Developer Tools. Go to Network tab. Tick `Preserve log`. Click the Next Page button. Please show us the request and response headers of the next request.

Comment: A very likely cause is that client.ClientName() is returning an empty string. So the value is getting passed. It's just empty. You can set a breakpoint on the redirect line and see what the value of the property is.

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to BorrowerRegistration page, did you check URL?
If It has no QueryString value then your Client Method returns NULL value. URL will be like :

```
BorrowerRegistration.aspx?Parameter=
```

Comment: I have even tried this Response.Redirect("BorrowerRegistration.aspx?Parameter=JoJo"); and still no value gets passed to reationshipNameLabel.Text.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the URL has your parameters in it, if it has them then you have to do something like this in **BorrowerRegistration.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    if (Request.QueryString["Parameter"] != null)
        relationshipNameLabel.Text = Request.QueryString["Parameter"].ToString();                  
}
```